# Accessing fields of child class via shared_ptr

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, shared-ptr

Is it possible to access fields in the instance of child class via `shared_ptr`? For instance, the code below does not compile. However, if I just declare a variable like `Bar bar(2)`, then I can access field `b` in a usual way, e.g. `bar._b`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    Bar(int b) : _b(b) {};
    const int _b;
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<Foo> bbar = make_shared<Bar>(3);
    cout << bbar->_b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the "however" have to do with it? Yes, if you make a `Bar` object you can access `Bar` member variables. But you couldn't access them through a `Foo*` raw pointer any more than you can access tham through a `shared_ptr<Foo>` smart pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is that you are using `shared_ptr<Foo>` as your data type, do you cannot access `_b`. There are 2 different way to solve this problem, each can be used in specific situations:

**1. Use derived type rather than base type**

Use `auto` or `shared_ptr<Bar>` for your data type:

```
shared_ptr<Bar> bbar = make_shared<Bar>(3); // or use `auto`
```

**2. Polymorphic dynamic cast**

Cast your data type before using:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() {}
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    Bar(int b) : _b(b) {};
    const int _b;
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<Foo> bbar = make_shared<Bar>(3);
    auto fbar = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Bar>(bbar);
    cout << fbar->_b;
    return 0;
}
```

But in this case you need to make `Foo` a polymorphic type. That's why I added `virtual ~Foo() {}` to `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that base class (`Foo`) does not inherit the data members of a derived class (`Bar`). If you would like to access a derived class data member through a base class, you would need to use virtual functions to do so.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
  virtual int val() = 0; // pure virtual function that needs to be overridden
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    Bar(int b) : _b(b) {};
    const int _b;
    virtual int val() { return _b; }
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<Foo> bbar = make_shared<Bar>(3);
    cout << bbar->val();
    return 0;
}
```